# Firebase OnMessageReceived() is not being called when message sent from console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on Firebase Cloud messaging service
I have followed the docs spot on but still encountering this weird issue which i have never face before. Issue is the OnMessageReceived() function is not being called all the time when ever i push the messages from console.To make that work i need to Invalidate the cache & restart my IDE & then reinstall the app in the emulator. I am not sure why is this happening at the first place. The Firebase Assistant also shows that everything is in Place. I am placing the code below.

Thanks in Adavance.

```
    package com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample;

    import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
    import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        System.out.println("Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.

    }
  }
```

---

```
package com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        //if the message contains data payload
        //It is a map of custom keyvalues
        //we can read it easily
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            //handle the data message here
        }

        //getting the title and the body
//        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        //then here we can use the title and body to build a notification

        System.out.println("\n \n \n \n \n ************** Message From FireBaSE ************* \n \n " + body);
//
   //     Toast.makeText(this, "Message Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }



    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
        System.out.println("Messages Deleted");
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n" + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken().toString()+ "\n\n\n\n\n");

    }
}
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

---

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
07-19 17:45:39.215 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
07-19 17:45:39.272 6105-6105/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample I/System.out: eO-_t8px37Q:APA91bE0wZTbCLb1Kq0-lJ5vNSDFsFtBIXxFTJdXAQK7eJCU7ObzK3bTb8xVpJXrmC_GNw9BVhYRCxqrmWMNSbatgz7GMkvpofldTopCYW0_8LrO3jtDXN7c0k23tW9LfRWSPJNM5torC19uOT2Zm-JLwvK78wEvDw
07-19 17:45:39.285 6105-6128/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-19 17:45:39.297 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Connecting to remote service
07-19 17:45:39.298 6105-6105/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/Atlas: Validating map...
07-19 17:45:39.330 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
07-19 17:45:39.333 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
07-19 17:45:39.339 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=5535374082724063558}]
07-19 17:45:39.371 6105-6128/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-19 17:45:39.373 6105-6128/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-19 17:45:39.374 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
07-19 17:45:39.376 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
07-19 17:45:39.382 6105-6128/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xae8e22e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
07-19 17:45:39.383 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 6221785
07-19 17:45:39.398 6105-6128/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae8e22e0: ver 2 0
07-19 17:45:39.406 6105-6128/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
07-19 17:45:39.417 6105-6128/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae8e22e0: ver 2 0
07-19 17:45:39.549 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/FA: Connected to remote service
07-19 17:45:39.549 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
07-19 17:45:44.629 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
07-19 17:45:49.006 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Session started, time: 6231895
07-19 17:45:49.013 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/FA: Logging event (FE): session_start(_s), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=5535374082724063558}]
07-19 17:45:49.026 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Connecting to remote service
07-19 17:45:49.029 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample D/FA: Connected to remote service
07-19 17:45:49.030 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
07-19 17:45:54.037 6105-6125/com.danaraddi.amazonsnsexample V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Note : I have also followed this docs
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?authuser=0

With the newer firebase version by removing all depreciated functions like onTokenRefresh() etc.This behavior is still same

Comment: What kind of notification are you sending from the console? Is it a notification only message or does it have a data payload? Is your app open when you send this notification?

Comment: It is just a simple text, My App is in Foreground. @JudeFernandes

Comment: From what I recall notification only messages are handled by the system directly and will not call the `OnMessageReceived`, try sending a notification that also has a data payload, that should surely call the `OnMessageReceived`.

Comment: @JudeFernandes i have also added logs for a better insight

Comment: have u tried sending notification  with rest client tool from link.https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: @VINAYDANARADDI the log seems fine, I'm guessing you use the token to send an fcm to the device? Did you try sending a data message?

Comment: I tried using Token. & I am trying to send data message